# Explanation on the symmetry between identity axiom and cut rule

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, sequent-calculus

In [Proofs And Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf) at the beginning of 5.1.4 Girard says that the identity axiom is somewhat complementary to the cut rule, more specifically 'The identity axiom says that $C$ (on the left) is stronger than $C$ (on the right); this [cut] rule states the converse truth, i.e. $C$ (on the right) is stronger than $C$ (on the left).'

Can someone explain this to me a little bit further?  I only vaguely get the first part of the statement, that the identity axiom roughly says that $C$ (on the left) implies $C$ (on the right), but I don't know what to make of the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll add a "long comment" to fweth's one* ...

Consider the rules for $\to$ (the conditional). They are respectively :

> $$(\to \text {-left)} \ \ \frac{\Gamma \vdash \Delta, C \quad D \vdash \Pi, \Lambda}{C \to D, \Gamma, \Pi \vdash \Delta, \Lambda}$$

and

> $$(\to \text {-right)} \ \ \frac{C, \Gamma \vdash \Delta, D}{\Gamma \vdash \Delta, C \to D}.$$

Omitting the contexts and replacing $D$ with $C$, they look like :

> $$(\to \text {-left)} \ \ \frac{ \vdash C \quad C \vdash }{C \to C \vdash }$$

and

> $$(\to \text {-right)} \ \ \frac{C \vdash C}{\vdash C \to C}.$$

Now, we can "read" them as meaning respectively :

- the *axiom rule* licences the derivation of the tautological : $C \to C$,

while :

- the *cut rule* licences us to "discard" the contradictory : $\lnot (C \to C)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think he means that if we chose all sequences in the cut rule $$\frac{\underline{A}\vdash C,B\quad\underline{A}',C\vdash\underline{B'}}{\underline{A},\underline{A}'\vdash\underline{B},\underline{B}'}$$ to be empty, then we can informally read it as '($\vdash C$ a.k.a. $C$-on-the-right) *and* ($C\vdash$ a.k.a. *not* $C$-on-the-left) *implies* ($\vdash$ a.k.a. *contradiction*)', hence $C$ on the right implies $C$ on the left.

Comment: Good consideration ...